# Is it possible to duplicate (mirror) an existing window?

Tags: window, duplicate, mirroring

I attend a webinar that broadcasts video which is much larger than my screen resolution.  I have multiple monitors and would like to be able to view one half of the webcast on one monitor and the other half on my 2nd, without logging in twice and using double the bandwidth.  Basically it would just be a mirror duplicate of the window.

I found a [mac version](http://www.fabiancanas.com/Projects/DuplicateWindows/) of what I'd like, but can't find any for Windows.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: So, wait, you want to duplicate the window rather than stretch the output across both displays?  Wouldn't you just have the same partial image twice then?  I think I am missing something here.

Comment: Unfortunately, the video stretches vertically rather than horizontally.  I can't lay my monitors out that way.

Answer (score 0):

I know that some operating systems (like Linux) let you define the relative positions of multiple monitors. For example, MonitorA is "Below" or "Left of" MonitorB. This would let your tall window span over 2 monitors correctly. Have you looked for a similar setting in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Tom's suggestion, you can go into the Display properties (Control Panel -> Display) and then to the Settings tab where your monitors are displayed. From there, you can reposition the monitors so that they are virtually vertically aligned as opposed to virtually horizontally aligned (moving the mouse up to the top of the screen past the first monitor enters the second monitor as opposed to moving it to the right on the other screen).

Not sure if this is what you're looking for specifically. As far as literally duplicating a window, I'm not sure if that's even technically possible within Windows. [Mac OS X uses X.Org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Implementations) (as does most Linux distributions) which was a windowing system built around the network and terminals, so displaying windows on other systems (or duplicating a view, in this case) isn't a problem. That said, if the Webinar is available to be viewed within Linux, you could set up something akin to that.

Comment: OS X dosen't use X by default - it uses quartz. X is only supported for porting software from other *nixes